# Items not adding to inventory text based game in python

Tags: python, text-based

So I have been working on this text based game in python for a project and I have gotten it where I can move around but can not get it where it will pick up the item itself. any help would be greatly appreciated. I am no expert as I am current going to school for programming and still learning.

```
def game_instructions():   # print a main menu and the commands
    print("Killer Clown Text Adventure Game")
    print("You must collect all six items to win the game or be killed by the Killer Clown!!")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West, Exit")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


rooms = {
    'Front Gates': {'South': 'Games Area', 'East': 'Ticket Booth', 'item': 'none'},
    'Games Area': {'North': 'Front Gates', 'East': 'Prize Area', 'West': 'Food Court', 'South': 'Storage Shed',
                   'item': 'Big Mallet'},
    "Food Court": {'East': 'Games Area', 'item': 'pie'},
    'Prize Area': {'West': 'Games Area', 'North': 'Fun House', 'item': 'Net'},
    'Fun House': {'South': 'Prize Area', 'item': 'none'},
    'Storage Shed': {'North': 'Games Area', 'East': 'Parking Lot', 'item': 'Flash Light'},
    'Ticket Booth': {'West': 'Front Gates', 'item': 'Clown-B-Gone Book'},
    'Parking Lot': {'West': 'Storage Shed', 'item': 'Keys'}
}


def room_movement(current_room, move, rooms):
    current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    return current_room

def user_info():
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))
    print('Inventory: ', inventory)
    print('*' * 25)


def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:    # if statement
        return rooms[current_room]['item']     # return statement
    else:
        return 'This room has no item!'    # return statement


game_instructions()
input('Press Enter to Continue')

inventory = []
current_room = 'Front Gates'
move = ''


while current_room != 'Fun House':
    user_info()
    move = input('Enter your next move.\n').title().split()
    item = get_item(current_room)
    print('There seems to be an item nearby')
    if move == 'take':
        move = input('What do you want to take? ').title().split()
        if move in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            inventory.append(item)
        else:
            print(f"There's no {item} here.")
    if len(move) >= 2 and move[0].lower() == 'go' and move[1].capitalize() in rooms[current_room].keys():
        current_room = room_movement(current_room, move[1].capitalize(), rooms)
        continue
    elif len(move) == 1 and move[0].lower() == 'exit':
        current_room = 'exit'
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
```

Comment: What symptoms do you see? I can see some code which looks like it appends an item to inventory.

Comment: The tag [tag:pygame] is to be used only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library.

Comment: when entering in move 'take' its suppose to prompt the command what do you want to take and instead just shows invalid command. also wont add items to inventory just states its an invalid command